# how to secure/ httponly cookies

Tags: nginx, cookies, tomcat8.5

I have configured nginx as Proxy server and my backend is tomcat8.5 on Redhat7. I have configure SSL in nginx. I would like to have cookie in **secure** and **httponly** but my header shows only JSESSIONID in cookie.

my result:-  Cookie:JSESSIONID=D442DD723352EA8354E4D .

i'm seeking of below result 
[click on here- pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWfFO.png)

I have follow below solution , but that was not worked for httpOnly.
https://geekflare.com/secure-cookie-flag-in-tomcat/